# Singularity of $\log(\frac{1}{z^2})$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z) = \log\left(\frac{1}{z^2}\right)$

I am trying to see the type of singularity $f$ has at $0$.

I can see that the limit of $f$ at $0$ is $\infty$. So it is a pole.

Now I am trying to look at the order of the pole. I tried looking at the expansion. I can't find its expansion about $0$.

Please help

Comment: How do you define $\log(z)$?

Comment: The point $z=0$ is NOT a pole.  It IS a branch point.

Comment: A pole is a certain sort of isolated singularity. To be a pole the function would have to be analytic in $\{z:0<|z|<r\}$ for some $r>0$. (So your function does not have an isolated singularity, so it does not _have_ a Laurent series about the origin.)

Answer (score 0):

By using the standard definition of $\log z$ as
$$
\log z=\log re^{i\theta}=\log r+i\theta\quad,\quad -\frac{\pi}{2}<\theta\le \frac{\pi}{2},
$$
the branch $z=re^{i\pi}$ is a non-analytic branch for this function. It follows that the branch $\{z:\frac{1}{z^2}\le0\}=\{z:z=iy\ \ ,\ \ y\in\mathbb R\}$ is a non-analytic branch of $\log\frac{1}{z^2}$ on which $z=0$ resides. Hence, $z=0$ is not an isolated singularity.